# How to use HMAC for authenticating multiple messages

Tags: hash, mac, hmac

The standard HMAC function, $H(K, m)$, authenticates a single message $m$.

Instead, I'd like to authenticate 2 messages, like this: $$H'(K, m_1, m_2)$$

The simplest solution, $H(K, m_1||m_2)$, confuses e.g. `"ab"+"cd"` or `"abc"+"d"` as messages.

Would this be secure instead: $H(H(K, m_1), m_2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. $\:$ However, note that *also* using $K$ in the ordinary way would be a huge vulnerability, since

learning $H(K,m_1)$ would allow anyone to authenticate $m_1$ together with arbitrary messages $m_2$.

The two solutions $H(K,$[prefixfree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code)$\hspace{.02 in}(m_1)\hspace{.02 in}||\hspace{.02 in}m_2)$ and

if $\: \operatorname{length}(m_2) < \operatorname{length}(m_1\hspace{-0.02 in}) \:$ then $H(K,1\hspace{.02 in}||\hspace{.02 in}$prefixfree$\hspace{.02 in}(m_2)\hspace{.02 in}||\hspace{.02 in}m_1)$ else $H(K,0\hspace{.02 in}||\hspace{.02 in}$prefixfree$\hspace{.02 in}(m_1)\hspace{.02 in}||\hspace{.02 in}m_2\hspace{.02 in})$

are probably faster. $\:$ (For either of those, also using $K$ in the ordinary way 
would merely let an adversary authenticate specific extra messages.)

Answer (score 1):

If the hashing function $H$ is secure, then $H(H(K, m_1), m_2)$ is secure. But at the cost of applying $H$ twice.